# permanently setting vim as the $EDITOR for crontab

Tags: bash, cron, environment-variables

I am trying to tell my terminal to use vim instead of vi when editing crontab by executing `export EDITOR=vim`. But closing the terminal and opening a new one just resets the session. How do I change that?

Answer (score 7):

```
echo 'export EDITOR=vim' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: also works for  neovim with small change : ```echo 'export EDITOR=nvim' >> ~/.bashrc```

Answer (score 0):

From the `man` page:

> -e     Edits the current crontab using the editor specified by the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables.

Therefore unfortunately there is no crontab specific `EDITOR` setting, however, you could create an alias to invoke the `vim` editor prior to editing your cron:

```
alias crontabvim="export EDITOR=vim;crontab $@"
```

`$@` will apply all subsequent arguments to the `crontab` command.

This can be saved in your `~/.bashrc` file for session persistance.